# unity7.log file eating disk space

Tags: unity, logs

This file .cache/unity7.log in my home directory is eating into my disk space. It increases to several GB in minutes and eventually I get the message that I am running low on disk space. At this time the file size is more than 100 GB. So I deleted this file but it keeps getting created again and eating into disk space.

Comment: This sounds like a bug. Could you do a `tail -f ~/.cache/unity7.log` and see whether there is a particular log message that is repeatedly being written to the log?

Comment: I am getting a lot of messages for this:-    (xpad:5230): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

Comment: Spotify can also be the cause of this, filling the log with `[file_system_monitor_linux.cpp:104] Check failed: errno == EINTR`. It might not technically be unity's fault, but it should not just dump all that data into a log file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue in Xpad, as described [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/xpad/+bug/1426913). Probably the messages will go away if you terminate Xpad. If so, I suggest you add yourself to the people whom this bug affects. Go to the above page and log in with your UbuntuOne credentials, or create an account if you don't have these. If possible, try the suggestion by the package maintainer: download the source file and compile/install from source.

Comment: bulls eye man. Xpad was the culprit. Thanks for the help :)